# 'svn' binary could not be found in PATH error in Sublime text 2

Tags: svn, sublimetext2

I installed Sublime Text 2 recently, and installed all the required packages like `Sublime linter, Rope, Modific` etc.,

But after opening the editor and when trying to do something, i am getting the below error within a `POP-UP` frequently and could able to work

So how to avoid it

```
'svn' binary could not be found in PATH

Consider using `vcs` property to specify PATH

PATH is: /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/username/bin
```

Comment: Are you trying to use svn, or is it some background process in sublime text? It should be easy enough to install if you need it: `yum install subversion` on a Red Hat-style Linux, or `apt-get install subversion` on an Ubuntu/Debian-style. If you don't want it, there's probably a menu option somewhere to tell Sublime to not check for SVN-versioned documents.

Answer (score 2):

It's perhaps `Modific` package of Sublime why you see that error. `Modific` requires qualified path to `git` executable installed on your machine and it isn't finding it.

Strangely, `Modific` wont look past the Sublime Package Default/User Settings.

> Go to Sublime Text 2 --> Preferences --> Package Settings --> Modific --> Settings - User.

Now you require to determine the path to your `vcs` or in your case: `svn` executable.

On most *nix systems: you can type `which svn` on terminal to get qualified installation path

Now add the following to aforementioned **empty** `Settings - User` file:

```
{
    "vcs": [
        {"name": "svn", "dir": ".svn", "cmd": "terminal output of **which svn** mentioned above"}
    ]
}
```

> > **NOTE**: Do not update the `Settings-Default` file as your changes will be over-written if `Modific` updates

Hope this helps!

Comment: had the same problem but with git (modific / sublime text 3), and this solved my problem (changed `git` to `/usr/bin/git` (osx el capitan). Thank you @Vikram !

Comment: yw!! I am glad it was helpful :)